# How do you set text on Telerik Rad Numeric Textbox

Tags: c#, telerik

I have come across a lot of threads on how to format the text in the box for input, but I believe this question is different enough to be on its own because I cannot find an answer.

I need to format text after the user inputs a value in the rad numeric textbox.
The user is required to enter a number between .001 and .999. After this input, the returned value must be the number in percent form followed by a percent sign

ie: 
if the user enters .500, then the box must return 50.000%

This seems simple in theory, but I keep getting this error

**Text property cannot be set. Input string was not in a correct format**

Here is the code I am using.
C#

```
double pct = rntb.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
string result = pct.ToString("P3");
rntb.Text = result;
```

ASP

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rntb" runat="server" Type="Percent" Value="1" OnTextChanged="rntb_TextChanged">
```

Comment: There is an option on the Telerik control to set Type to "Percent" and you could setting the MaxValue

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use JS for this? The Type to Percent is already on the code under the ASP section. The problem is that the user will be entering a value from .001 to .999

Comment: Don't now, but why is the user entering a value of .500 and you must covert it to 50.000%, why is he not entering a value of 50.000?

Comment: I'm not sure, it was what the user requested. It doesn't make much sense to me either

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `RadMaskedTextBox`

```
  <telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="RadMaskedTextBox1" runat="server" Mask=".###"
            Width="100%" PromptChar="_" />
```

Get your value using `RadMaskedTextBox1.Text;` , it will return `RadMaskedTextBox`'s text (number only) without `.`(dot) .

For example

```
.001 => 001  
.500 => 500  
.999 => 999
```

So , you have to convert likes

```
string yourPercentage = (Double.Parse(RadMaskedTextBox1.Text)/ 10).ToString() + "%";
```

**Edit**

You can change and test this method ,

```
            RadMaskedTextBox1.Text;
            RadMaskedTextBox1.TextWithLiterals;
            RadMaskedTextBox1.TextWithPrompt;
            RadMaskedTextBox1.TextWithPromptAndLiterals;
```

Good Luck :)

Comment: This almost works. I believe the mask prevents the value from being returned as "87.000%". What gets returned is .87_

Comment: Yes, the .87_ is the result of my test, the mask simply keeps it in that format, which may tell that there is no (easy) way around this

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
double pct = rntb.Value.GetValueOrDefault();
rntb.Text = String.Format("{0:P3}.", pct);
```